# Azure APIM Developer Portal Reports Tab does not show anything

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to use the **REPORTS** tab on the APIM developer portal.
As of now it does not show anything. The page itself shows fine, but all numbers are zeroes there.
While the Azure Portal does show the traffic. I have simple questions:

- Has anybody successfully used this tab?
- Is there any trick that I should do to see something there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login on the Developer portal.
Subscribe for the product and make requests in the test console for API

[image]

Check reports in 5-10 minutes. Reports will show API statistics for the current user.

[image]

Comment: Essentially Dev Portal shows the traffic only for the subscriptions that the logged in developer owns. Not for the whole traffic. Docs do not mention that.